Get every key in JSON whose value is an array and its path
I have a JSON file, and for some keys their value is an array. The JSON can go up to an unspecified depth. I would like to know how to extract all the keys whose value is an array, and also the JSON path to that array.
Example schema:
[
    {
        "field1": "x",
        "field2": ["y", "z"],
        "field3": [
            {
                "field4": "a",
                "field5": ["b", "c"]
            },
            {
                "field4": "d",
                "field5": ["e", "f"]
            }
        ],
        "field6": "g"
    }
]

From this, I want they keys field2, field3, field5 and their paths e.g. field2, field3, field3[0][field5], field3[1][field5]
I have got the following code which can identify all keys in a JSON file, but not the type of value it holds nor its path:
def get_keys(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            yield k
            yield from list(get_keys(v))
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for o in d:
            yield from list(get_keys(o))


You're going to have to store every path while descending into a dict or a list, because you never know when you'll reach a list value. (As an aside, your paths should all start with 0).

This will likely get you on track Find the path of the targeted values in a nested python dictionary and list. I'm guessing you just need to test for isinstance() rather than a value.

import json

json_data = """
[{
    "field1": "x",
    "field2": ["y", "z"],
    "field3": [
        {
            "field4": "a",
            "field5": ["b", "c"]
        },
        {
            "field4": "d",
            "field5": ["e", "f"]
        }
    ],
    "field6": "g",
    "field7": {
                 "field8": "h",
                 "field9": ["i","j"]
              }
}]
"""


def find_lists(data, path=""):

    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for key, value in data.items():
            current_path = f"{path}.{key}" if path else key
            find_lists(value, current_path)

    elif isinstance(data, list):
        if path != "":
            print(f"Key: {path.split(".")[-1]}   Path: {path}")
        for index, item in enumerate(data):
            current_path = f"{path}[{index}]"
            find_lists(item, current_path)


mydata = json.loads(json_data)
find_lists(mydata)

The output is:
Key: field2   Path: [0].field2
Key: field3   Path: [0].field3
Key: field5   Path: [0].field3[0].field5
Key: field5   Path: [0].field3[1].field5
Key: field9   Path: [0].field7.field9


You defined your data as a list containing a dictionary.  If you don't want the paths to start out with "[0].", just make the data a dictionary (remove the outer square brackets).
